# Abstract geometry proof

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

Let $\{Y_1, L_1\}$ and $\{Y_2, L_2\}$ be abstract geometries, where $Y_1, Y_2$ are sets whose elements are points and $L_1,L_2$ are sets whose elements are lines. Let $Y = Y_1 \cup Y_2$ and $L= L_1 \cup L_2$. Prove that $\{Y, L\}$ is an abstract geometry.

To prove that it is an abstract geometry then I must show that for every two points $A,B \in Y_1$ (or $Y_2$) there is a line $l \in L_1$ (or $L_2$) with $A,B \in l$. And every line has at least two points.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems it may not hold without more assumptions. In $\mathbb{R^3}$ let $\{Y_i,L_i\}$ be the collection of usual lines and points which happen to lie all in the plane $z=i.$

Now if you take one point with $z=1$ and another with $z=2$ there is no line connecting them, in the union of the two sets of lines.

Comment: What if it is only in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R^2}$ one could take the first abstract geometry as the points of the $x$ axis, and the single line being the $x$ axis. Take the second abstract geometry to be the points of the $y$ axis, and single line the $y$ axis. Then there is no line in the union of the lines which connects $(1,0)$ from the first geometry to $(0,1)$ of the second geometry.